# How to solve Dining Philosophers with Mutex in Java?

Tags: java, mutex, dining-philosopher

My java project has 3 java class. There is Main,Philosoper and chStick. I solved Dining Philosophers Problem with using boolean value isTaken.

in the project chStick.java like below. This class control that chopstick in use or not use.

```
class ChStick
{
   private int id;
   private boolean isTaken;

   ChStick (int id)
   {  
       this.id=id;
   }

   synchronized void get () throws InterruptedException
   {
       while(isTaken){
          wait();
       }

       isTaken=true;
   }

   int getID ()
   {
       return id;
   }

   synchronized void put () throws InterruptedException
   {
      isTaken=false;
   }
}
```

This code works succesfully.When I use Semaphore instead of boolean value isTaken, it is also works succesfully.

My problem is rewrite this class using Mutex. I tried lots of methods but it has still not worked. It must use Mutex class .

Edit:

```
class Philos extends Thread// #9 - Make this class to be inherited from Thread class
{
   private String name;
   private ChStick left, right;

   Philos (String name, ChStick left, ChStick right)
   {
     // #10 - Assign this philosopher a name, his left and rigt chopsticks.
       this.left=left;
       this.right=right;
       this.name=name;
   }

    @Override
   public void run ()
   {
       while (true)
       {
          try
          {
              System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name + " is thinking.");

              // #11 - Make philosopher sleep for a RANDOM time.
              Thread.sleep(1000);

              System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name + " is hungry.");



              if (left.getID () < right.getID ())
              {
                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " getting left ChStick.");

            // #12 - Make philosopher to get left chopstick.
                  left.get();

                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " got left ChStick."+left.getID());
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " getting right ChStick.");

                  // #13 - Make philosopher to get right chopstick.
                  right.get();

                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " got right ChStick."+right.getID());
              }

              // Get other ChStick.

              if (left.getID () < right.getID ())
              {
                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " getting right ChStick.");

            // #14 - Make philosopher to get (left or right)? chopstick.
                  right.get();

                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " got right ChStick."+right.getID());
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " getting left ChStick.");

                  // #15 - Make philosopher to get (left or right)? chopstick.
                  left.get();


                  System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                      " got left ChStick."+left.getID());
              }

              System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name + " is eating.");

              // #16 - Make philosopher sleep for a RANDOM time.
              Thread.sleep(2000);

              // #17 - Make philosopher to put the left chopstick down.

              System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                  " putting down left ChStick."+left.getID());
              left.put();

              // #17 - Make philosopher to put the right chopstick down.

              System.out.println ("Philosopher " + name +
                                  " putting down right ChStick."+right.getID());
              right.put();
          } 
          catch (InterruptedException e) {}
       }
   }
}



public class Main
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {                                                 

    // #1 - Here you should create chopstick instances 
    //      and number them using the structure defined in its class definition. 

    // ChStick cs1 = new ChStick ..
       ChStick cs1 = new ChStick(1);
       ChStick cs2 = new ChStick(2);
       ChStick cs3 = new ChStick(3);
       ChStick cs4 = new ChStick(4);
       ChStick cs5 = new ChStick(5);


    // #2 - Here you should create Philosopher instances
    //      and assign them names, their right and left chopsticks.
    //      BE CAREFUL IN WHICH ORDER THEY SIT AROUND THE TABLE 

    // Philos p1 = new Philos ("P1"...)
      Philos p1 = new Philos("P1",cs1,cs5);
      Philos p2 = new Philos("P2",cs2,cs1);
      Philos p3 = new Philos("P3",cs3,cs2);
      Philos p4 = new Philos("P4",cs4,cs3); 
      Philos p5 = new Philos("P5",cs5,cs4);

    // #3 - Start p
      p1.start();
      p2.start();
      p3.start();
      p4.start();
      p5.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no Mutex class in the Java standard library.

Comment: Yes I know but there is Mutex class http://kickjava.com/src/javax/concurrent/Mutex.java.htm

Comment: @Marko Topolnik you are obviously right, yet there is a Semaphore class. If you have a semaphore with only 1 permit, you essentially have a mutex.

Comment: @bowmore OP seems to be aware of Semaphore and it works for him.

Comment: I already used a Semaphore class with only 1 permit, I know that it is  a mutex. But I have to use Mutex class. import com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.Mutex; this import for Mutex class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is a variation on the [Conductor solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Conductor_solution).

Your mutex would function as the conductor, but would allow only one philosopher at a time to take forks and dine.

So any phislopher thread would wait for a successful `acquire()` on the mutex, take the forks which must be available since no other philosopher is dining. Then dine, put the forks down, and call `release()` on the mutex.

Comment: I added other classes on my post. You can examine. I did like you said with Semaphore. But how to change my codes using Mutex class?

Comment: The ChStick class should replace the boolean isTaken with a Mutex, the `get()` calls `acquire()` on it, the `put()` calls `release()` on it. Then your code will expose the deadlock problem. At that point you can introcude the conductor as described in my answer to solve the deadlock.

Comment: I could not deadlock problem @bowmore. I didn't understand introducing  the conductor.

Comment: I've taken your code and added the Mutex for the chopsticks and added the Conductor to solve the deadlock : here's a pastebin http://pastebin.com/3Xiuv9Vf

Comment: @bownmore Thanks a lot. Your conductor class solved the deadlock problem and I understood how to do it. Thank you for your interest.